# Why would someone use the gem foreigner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, foreign-keys, foreigner

This is most likely a noob question since people use this gem and a lot of people love it, but I don't get the purpose.  I'm looking at a project and its been used here many times in places such as `t.references :foreign_key_table_name , :foreign_key => true`, `add_foreign_key :table :foreign_key_table_name, :options`, and in a create `t.foreign_key :foreign_key_table_name`.  Hope those weren't confusing since they're out of context.

But I don't get how this is different from what rails does built in with `t.references :foreign_key_table_name` or from me just adding `t.integer :foreign_key_table_name_id`?  does it simply make it more readable by making clear that this is a 'foreign key'?  I could just add a comment instead of a gem if thats the case...  The only advantage I see is that you can move options such as `:dependent` into the migration instead of having it in the model, but who cares?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some database engines support legit foreign key constraints: if someone tries to save a `Child` with a `parent_id` of 5, but there's no `Parent` with `id` 5, then the database itself (not Rails) will reject the record if there's a foreign key constraint linking `children.parent_id` and `parents.id`.

A foreign key can also specify what happens if the parent is deleted: in MySQL, for example, we can delete or nullify the dependent records, like how Rails does with `:dependent`, or even just straight-up reject the deletion and throw an error instead.

Since not all database engines offer this functionality, Rails offers to emulate it with `:dependent`, and it's nice to have it on the software level so that dependent child records can fire their `destroy` callbacks when the parent is deleted. Since the feature is engine-independent and therefore pretty much schema-independent, Rails doesn't handle the creation/deletion of foreign keys. That's where `foreigner` comes in: if your engine supports foreign key constraints, and you want that extra confident in your data integrity, `foreigner` can help with that.

Comment: @GiH: Oh, and it just now occurs to me why `:dependent` doesn't do this: since it's a model-level specification and can be added/removed at any time. It's built to be flexible, instead of demanding that the foreign key also be present in the database—which would be extra-weird, since not all Rails-supported database engines also support foreign keys.

Answer (score 6):

Resurrecting an old question here, but…

Having rails enforce the relationship is fine, within rails itself.

However, if your project grows to have code that also accesses these tables from other languages, that will not have the benefit of rails enforcing the relations. These foreign key constraints are baked into the SQL tables themselves, so can protect non-rails code.

This will also protect you if you need to perform datafixes or otherwise manipulate your data via native SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason is that some documentation tools for SQL look at foreign keys on the DB, so it is cool to have a gem that generates them. Rails 4 added the ability to define foreign keys in the same migration that creates the table with:

```
t.references :something, foreign_key: true
```

And the generators will do this for you if you use the `references` type. Rails adds an index on `something_id` by default when using `foreign_key` like this